# Making a prediction using Fixed Effects

Tags: r, predictive-models, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, lm

I have a simple data set for which I applied a simple linear regression model. Now I would like to use fixed effects to make a better prediction on the model. I know that I could also consider making dummy variables, but in reality is my data over several years and has more variables so I would like to avoid making dummies.

My data and code is similar to this:

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                   text="CompanyNumber ResponseVariable Year ExplanatoryVariable1 ExplanatoryVariable2
                   1 2.5 2000 1 2
                   1 4 2001 3 1
                   1 3 2002 5 7
                   2 1 2000 3 2
                   2 2.4 2001 0 4
                   2 6 2002 2 9
                   3 10 2000 8 3")

library(lfe)
fe <- getfe(felm(data = data, ResponseVariable ~ ExplanatoryVariable1 + ExplanatoryVariable2 | Year))
fe
lm.1<-lm(ResponseVariable ~ ExplanatoryVariable1 + ExplanatoryVariable2, data=data)                                   


prediction<- predict(lm.1, data) 
prediction

check_model=postResample(pred = prediction, obs = data$ResponseVariable)
check_model
```

For my real dataset I will make a prediction based on my test set but for simplicity I just use the trainingset here as well.

I would like to make a prediction with the help of the fixed effects that I found. But it does not seem to match the fixed effect right, anyone who knows how to use this `fe$effects`?

```
prediction_fe<- predict(lm.1, data) + fe$effect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the estimated fixed effects to the prediciton data frame.

```
library(lfe)

##data
d <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                   text="CompanyNumber ResponseVariable Year ExplanatoryVariable1 ExplanatoryVariable2
                   1 2.5 2000 1 2
                   1 4 2001 3 1
                   1 3 2002 5 7
                   2 1 2000 3 2
                   2 2.4 2001 0 4
                   2 6 2002 2 9
                   3 10 2000 8 3")

##regression
e<-felm(data = d, ResponseVariable ~ ExplanatoryVariable1 + ExplanatoryVariable2 | Year)

##fixed effects data
d.fe<-getfe(e)
##prediction sample
p<-d #could be a different sample, but with the same covariates
#add columns on fixed effects
p<-merge(p,d.fe[d.fe$fe=="Year",],by.x="Year",by.y="idx",all.x=T)
names(p)[grep("^effect$",names(p))]<-"effect.Year" 
#  if you have more than one fixed effect,
#  you should continue here, adapting the two lines above. eg. fixed effects on ComanyNumber
#reorder
p<-p[order(p$CompanyNumber,p$Year),]

##predict 
#coefficients:
predicted.values<-
  as.matrix(p[,rownames(e$coefficients)]) %*% (e$coefficients) + # covariates * coefficients
  p$effect.Year # fixed effects from years

##test 
round(predicted.values + e$residuals- p$ResponseVariable,6) # only works if the order of all observerations conincide
```

Note, that the data object name is now `d` not `data`, to avoide confusion.